# How do I get the latest from the repository using netbeans and svn

Tags: svn, netbeans

Suppose I'm happy to destroy all local changes.  When a right click a file and look at the subversion menu, there doesn't appear to be an option to simply replace everything with the latest from the repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform an **Update** on your working copy, and there's no risk on losing your local changes. You might get conflicts that you will have to resolve manually only for files that svn does not know how to merge.

On the other hand, if you'd like to destroy all your local changes, you have the **revert** command.

With a combination of both: first **revert** and then **update** you can achieve what you want and avoid possible conflict resolution.

Comment: What could `update` do after you already performed a `revert`? What would it be updating?

Comment: @Ian: `update` will substitute the files in your working copy with the latest version from the repository. `revert` just discards local changes, it doesn't connect to the repository to get the latest version files.

Comment: How does `revert` know what changes are my local changes? And once it figures that out, does it just delete those lines? What about the code that *was* there?

Comment: When you `check out` a working copy (wc), subversion creates a hidden `.svn` directory within each directory in your wc. There it keeps a pristine copy of each of the files in the directory, having the contents as they were in the repository for the version you checked out, or performed the last `update`. That's how, even being off-line, it's able to know that you have local changes (via `svn status`). The `revert` command just replaces the file having local changes with the version kept within the `.svn` directory. Further info at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do an update. If the update does not throw an conflict then your local changes are irrelevant. If there is a conflict usually there should be a option window.

In the option window you could say "Accept Theirs". This is how it works in intellij and Tortoise..

Ofcourse to accomplish what you want very easily, you could just delete all the files (not the entire versioned diretcory, just the files ) and click on update latest from repository.